# Equally spacing matplotlib Gridspec plots with consideration of axes/ticklabels/titles

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I use matplotlib to make publication quality panels of plots, and something important to me is the precise spacing between axes, including their texts.  Gridspec and tightlayout (h_pad, w_pad) work well when all of my plots have the same size fonts and contain xlabel/ylabel (or not).  However, if one plot in a panel has an xlabel, all plots in the gridspec will be spaced to this distance (the maximum distance between any two plots needed to achieve the pad requested).  I would like plots to have equal distances apart with consideration of their texts. I have found that constrained layout can sometimes produce the desired behavior, however the arguments hspace and wspace control plot distancing in hard to understand units of "fraction of subplot size", and I haven't worked out how to set a wspace or hspace to produce and precise inches of padding I want.  (I want subplots to have the same distances between plots/texts, regardless of figsize or subplot dimensions when I make different figures).

My only solution has been to create separate gridspecs for plots with different labeling patterns (with or without xlabels for example), and place them on the plots using gs.tightlayout with a rect argument, taking into account the spacing I desire- this also requires aligning the gridspecs etc.

Is there any known solution for consistent inches of padding between subplots (inclusive of text)?

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# equal spacing
fig =plt.figure(figsize=(4,8), constrained_layout=False)
gs = mpl.gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1, 
                       figure =fig,
                        height_ratios = [1,1,1,], hspace=0, wspace=0)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2])

mpl.gridspec.rcParams['font.size'] = 72
# pad 1/4 an inch
gs.tight_layout(fig, h_pad=0.25, w_pad=0, pad = 0.25)
```

[image]

Unequal spacing

```
fig =plt.figure(figsize=(4,8), constrained_layout=False)
gs = mpl.gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1, 
                       figure =fig,
                        height_ratios = [1,1,1,], hspace=0, wspace=0)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2])

ax2.set_xlabel('testing', fontsize = 20)
# setting this param so that I know how big the pad should be in inches (fonsize % units used for h_pad) 72 pt = 1 inch 
mpl.gridspec.rcParams['font.size'] = 72
# pad 1/4 an inch
gs.tight_layout(fig, h_pad=0.25, w_pad=0, pad = 0.25)
```

[image]

Desired output looks like this
[image]

Comment: There is no "known solution" to this, because it's a pretty special requirement. Usually you want the axes to have an equal distance.

Comment: I would agree that generally people want axes to be equally spaced, but constrained layout already has exactly the behavior desired! The main issue I'm having is that "wspace" and"hspace" can't be set in inches, was hopeful that there could be some work around.

Comment: Mhh, suppose they could be set in inches, that wouldn't solve the problem of the **un**equal spacing between different subplots required here, right? Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: what I'm saying is that constrained_layout actually does solve this problem, and spaces them equally as desired (inclusive of texts), but I don't have the ability, like in tight_layout h_pad and w_pad, to set the spacing between plots in inches/points. (thats the only reason I'm using tight_layout instead)

Comment: The difference between `tight_layout` and `constrainedlayout` is that `constrainedlayout` does not care about any subplot parameters, it will simple shift the elements around until everything fits. But you can set padding for constrained layout as well, see [padding-and-spacing](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html#padding-and-spacing). Not sure if that is what you're after?